# Using external class during client side Mocha unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am running unit tests on a javascript class using Mocha using the follow methodology, firstly the test:

```
var base = require('../moduleone.js');

describe("some test", function() {
    it("description", function() {
    var check = base.toBeTested(dummyValue)
    //test is here ...
    });
});
```

the moduleone.js  containing function to be tested:

```
function toBeTested(category){
    //below I calling an assert function defined in moduletwo
    //works fine when running in browser
    assert(type(category)=='string','category is string type');
    //more code..
    return something

module.exports.toBeTested = toBeTested;
```

moduletwo.js:

```
function assert(outcome, description) {
    //see code.tutsplus.com quick and easy javascript testing with assert
    var li = outcome ? 'pass' : 'fail';
    if (li == 'fail') {
        console.log('FAIL: '+description);
    }
    else {
        console.log('PASS: '+description);
    }
}
```

The issue I have is mocha doesn't know anything about moduletwo and when the moduleone function calles the function in moduletwo mocha throws a ReferenceError: assert is not defined. How can I link all my dependencies so that mocha can see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `moduleone.js` be sure that you are `require`ing `moduletwo.js` to bring your `assert` function into scope for `moduleone.js`. Otherwise, you get a `ReferenceError`, not for any reasons with `mocha`, but because `moduleone` does not have access to `assert`.

```
// moduletwo.js
function assert(outcome, description) { /* your functionality */ }

module.exports = assert


// moduleone.js
var assert = require('./moduletwo')

function toBeTested(category) { /* your functionality that uses assert */ }

module.exports.toBeTested = toBeTested
```

Now, with regards to that tutorial. If you are following it to learn how to *make* an easy assert module, that is fine. But if you are trying to test some code that does something else, consider using an existing assertion library like [chai](http://chaijs.com/). For example:

```
// example.test.js
var expect = require('chai').expect
var isValidCategory = require('./is-valid-category')

describe('isValidCategory(category)', function () {

  it('validates string categories', function () {

    expect(isValidCategory('A String Category')).to.be.true

  })

  it('does not validate non-string categories', function () {

    expect(isValidCategory(['an', 'array', 'somehow'])).to.be.false

  })

})

// is-valid-category.js
module.exports = function isValidCategory(category) {

  return typeof category === 'string'
}
```

Comment: for the case given when I exported one function from a module your solution works perfectly. However I require tens of functions from several files so I exported each function from moduletwo eg module.exports.assert = assert; module.exports.type = type; then added to module1 the code: var utils = require('./moduletwo.js') and called each function using: utils.assert(utils.type(category)...); The problem is my app is client side only so exposing functions through require won't work. Of course I could add everything to one big file but is there another way?

Comment: Your requirement of having multiple properties on `module.exports` is ok. Check out [browserify](http://browserify.org/) for bundling CommonJS modules for the client.

Comment: Great, note my use of 'assert' was to use java-like assertion in the client side code during development. For unit-test assertions I am using chai.

Comment: Ah, I see, I will have to keep that approach in mind. Kent C. Dodds has an interesting module called [api-check](https://github.com/kentcdodds/api-check) that I have been meaning to look at.